# what is the right answer in infix to postfix convertion

Tags: math, compiler-construction

I have the next infix expression:

```
(i730 + ssg2LQ) + ((+ G0 /(3064 + 68324.06)) / 28)
```

and I try to convert it to postfix notation, for this I used some on-line converters and all of them gave me the answer

```
1730 sg2LQ + G0 3064 68324.06 + / + 28 / +
```

but someone told me that the answer was

```
i730 sg2LQ + G0 + 3064 68324.06 + / 28 / +
```

and now I am confused, who is right? who is wrong? how is this expression properly converted?

Answer (score 1):

The second answer

```
i730 sg2LQ + G0 + 3064 68324.06 + / 28 / +
```

is definitely wrong because it will first compute `(i730 + ssg2LQ) + G0`.

Perhaps this answer was obtained by a tool that was confused by unary `+`.